# XML Schema. Processing namespace-aware attribute values

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing

Part of my project involves heavy transformations of user-defined schema documents. I need to be able to change target namespaces, support type cross-references and build `wsdl` upon multiple schema documents.
One of the most commonly used operations is changing namespace prefix prior to importing schema into wsdl file. I'm using `org.xml.sax.ContentHandler` and it's `startPrefixMapping` method to handle namespaces. All works fine and flawless unless I want to change element types.

Here is simple schema fragment

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <complexType name="Param">
    <sequence>
      <element name="key" type="string"/>
      <element name="value" type="string"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
<!-- omitted -->
```

which must be placed inside wsdl as follows:

```
<definitions xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <types>
    <xs:schema>
      <xs:complexType name="Param">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string"/> <!-- 'xs:' to be added -->
          <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/> <!-- 'xs:' to be added -->
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
<!-- omitted -->
```

The problem is that some schema's attribute values (`type` in `<element>`, `base` in `<extension>`) are namespace-aware and are subject to change in the above example. As I can see, neither DOM, nor SAX parsers are able to handle this situation so I'm currently using ugly string operations to retrieve namespace info from particular attribute values.

Am I missing somethiing? Are there any api's, libraries or other schema-specific tools to handle such sort of tasks?

Comment: That is kind of bothersome... The prefix isn't part of a qualified name in terms of elements or attributes, but is part of character data. A parser wouldn't be aware of that inherently. I've once asked a question that [reminds me of your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634416/jaxb-bindings-file-namespace-aware-node-selection). Maybe you could pass the XML through an XSLT stylesheet that processes certain attributes' content (like `type`) when encountered in an element that falls in the schema namespace.

Comment: @G_H, thanks for comment. Using XSLT seems to be acceptable solution, especially after reading `jtahlborn`'s view on the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, this is a major bug in xml schema/wsdl.  utilizing the xml namespace prefixes inside of attribute values was a giant mistake (since the prefix values themselves are not significant, only placeholders for the actual namespaces).  unfortunately, i don't know of any good solution to the problem (i've had to implement virtually the same sort of idea: merging multiple user defined schemas into one schema/wsdl).  i do know that xerces has an [xml schema model api](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xs/index.html), but i don't know if it has support for merging together multiple schemas and generating the resulting output.

Answer (score 1):

SAX is a very low level to be using for reading schema documents. You'll remove a lot of hassle if you move to a higher level interface like XSLT. You'll remove even more hassle if you read the schema documents using a schema processor that turns them into a schema component model - both Xerces and Saxon can do this, and they aren't alone.