# Python: QName on node's attribute, lxml

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

In Python's lxml.etree, How do i add the namesapce to an attribute of a node like this one:
name space is:

```
XS_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
```

result looking for is:

```
<xs:element name="label" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
```

I tried this one but the result is not what i am looking for:

```
element = ET.SubElement(
    sequence,
    ET.QName(XS_NS, "element"),
    name="label",
    type=str(ET.QName(XS_NS, "string")),
)
```

Gave me:

```
<xs:element name="label" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, while an attribute it self may have a namespace, the value of the attribute doesn't consider namespaces:

```
<!-- this attribute has namespace prefix -->
<dummy xs:foo="bar"/>
<!-- this attribute has value of string containing colon -->
<dummy foo="xs:bar"/>
```

So you can simply put the "prefix" and the "value" as a single string altogether:

```
type="xs:string"
```

Related discussion: [XML Schema. Processing namespace-aware attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877684/xml-schema-processing-namespace-aware-attribute-values). There it's implicitly stated that a prefix in the attribute value isn't significant, only placeholders for the actual namespaces.

Comment: This is what i ended up doing, but it is not a very clean solution, it is hard codded, thanks for the suggestion !